# Simple WinJS ListView Binding

Tags: javascript, listview, binding, windows-8.1, winjs

I am developing a Windows 8.1 app, and I have some data I want to bind to a listview. For some reason, I am not able to have the data shown, and I am not quite sure where I am making the mistake.

HTML:

```
<div id="resultTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <div class="win-type-small result" data-win-bind="innerText:name"></div>
</div>
<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" id="resultsView"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var results = [{ name: "quebec" }, { name: "quebec1" }];
var dataList = new WinJS.Binding.List(results);
var resultsListView = document.getElementById("resultsView").winControl;
var resultTemplate = document.getElementById("resultTemplate");

resultsListView.itemTemplate = resultTemplate;
resultsListView.itemDataSource = dataList.dataSource;
```

I am calling WinJS.UI.processAll() at the top of my javascript.

Comment: Looks good to me. You'll have to provide your full code so we can see the page lifecycle functions and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with it, but you could try setting the `itemTemplate` in the html.

```
<div id="resultTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <div class="win-type-small result" data-win-bind="innerText:name"></div>
</div>
<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" id="resultsView" data-win-options="{ itemTemplate: select('#resultTemplate')}"></div>
```

Notice the new `data-win-options` attribute in ListView tag